# Output UML element Enterprise Architect

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

In Enterprise Architect I'm trying to model my Business Process through the Eriksson-Penker Business Modelling Profile which looks like this:

[image: Eriksson-Penker]

Everything goes well except for the Output element on the bottom right.
For some reason it doesn't exist in the Toolbox:

[image: Toolbox]

How can I get this Output Element here? I'm searching and searching in different toolboxes but I can't find it. Some help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out that if you choose 'New Model from Pattern' in the project browser, browse to 'Business' and then select the Eriksson-Penker Diagram that it makes the entire diagram for you and you only have to change the descriptions. So case closed!

[image: Model Wizard]

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple Object. Choose `Other/UML/Object/Object` from the toolbox and name it `Output`. It will appear underlined as in your diagram.

P.S. I see that the EP toolbox has an `Object` already. Use that in you're done.